# React Native: Building code on Jenkins: RCTAccessibilityManager.m: error: use of undeclared identifier 'JSCategory'

Tags: jenkins, react-native

I am trying to build an Unity+React app on a jenkins server. I am using cocoapods on the Jenkins server. I am copying the podfile to my src/ Unity dir and running `pod install'.

My podfile is as follows:

```
platform :ios, "7.0"
pod 'React'
pod 'React/Core'
pod 'React/RCTText'
pod 'React/RCTNetwork'
pod 'React/RCTWebSocket'
pod 'React/RCTImage'
pod 'React/RCTLinkingIOS'
pod 'React/RCTAdSupport'
pod 'React/RCTSettings'
pod 'React/RCTActionSheet'
pod 'React/ART'
```

My build command is as follows:

```
xcodebuild build -workspace AppName.xcworkspace -scheme Pods -  configuration Release ARCHS="armv7 arm64" -sdk iphoneos CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=bin/iPhone/Release
```

The build step gives me the following error:

```
/Users/sprocket/workspace/BarnStormer-iOS-Experimental/bin/app/game/build/iphone/src/Pods/React/React/Modules/RCTAccessibilityManager.m:133:28: error: expected ';' in 'for' statement specifier
02:38:16         for (NSString *__nonnull JSCategory in JSMultipliers) { 
02:38:16       /Users/sprocket/workspace/BarnStormer-iOS-Experimental/bin/app/game/build/iphone/src/Pods/React/React/Modules/RCTAccessibilityManager.m:133:28: error: use of undeclared identifier 'JSCategory'
02:38:16       /Users/sprocket/workspace/BarnStormer-iOS-Experimental/bin/app/game/build/iphone/src/Pods/React/React/Modules/RCTAccessibilityManager.m:134:33: error: use of undeclared identifier 'JSCategory'
02:38:16           NSNumber *m = JSMultipliers[JSCategory];
02:38:16                                       ^
02:38:16       /Users/sprocket/workspace/BarnStormer-iOS-Experimental/bin/app/game/build/iphone/src/Pods/React/React/Modules/RCTAccessibilityManager.m:135:71: error: use of undeclared identifier 'JSCategory'
02:38:16           NSString *UIKitCategory = [self.class UIKitCategoryFromJSCategory:JSCategory];
```

JSCategory seems to be part of the React core and I am still getting this error. Any help is appreciated.